# How to create typings alias in typescript the way we create dependency alias in babelrc？

Tags: typescript, react-native, visual-studio-code, typescript-typings

TL;DR:

**How to create typing alias in typescript the way we create dependency alias in babelrc?**

The full question:

Let's say I am developing for **iOS and web**, and would like to write **only one set of code**. I  am using `React-Native` and something that has an interface that is very similar to `React-Native`, for the sake of this question, let's call it `Respond-Native`(**a made-up name**).

In the project, I used a component called `<Picker />`. The `Picker` on `Respond-Native`(still the **made-up** library) has a property that is **not** present in `React-Native` called `onSwipe`.

But other than that, the rest of the interface is pretty much the same. Minute differences like this are all over `Respond-Native`.

And to make typing easier, I have two almost identical projects. **The only thing that is different** is that I added an alias to the `.babelrc` of the project that uses `Respond-Native`:

```js
// .babelrc

{
  ...
  "plugins": [
    ...
    ["module-resolver", {
      "root": ["./"],
      "alias": {

        // the alias is here
        "react-native": "respond-native"

      }
    }]
  ]
}
```

However, when I write `<Picker onChange={handleOnChange} onSwipe={handleOnSwipe} />`, the editor does not know about the dependency alias and have no idea where the prop `onSwipe` comes from.

Sorry for the long build-up.

My question is, how can I do the same in creating typing alias (like I did in babelrc) so that VS Code would know which type declaration to use when checking types? (given that `Respond-Native` also has a `Picker` type/interface declared)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TS has the same exact mechanism like babel namely path alias:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "paths": {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

However, due to the limitation that this config only applies to user source code rather than any `node_modules`, it needs a bit of effort to "guide" TS to understand your intention.

Take for example, `preact` is a lib with API highly resembles one of `react`. Say you write your code using `react` and later you want to switch to `preact` but don't want to change your code.

1. you organize your files in structure like

```
./
├── node_modules/
│   ├── react/
│   └── preact/
├── typings/
│   └── react/
└── src/
    └── main.ts
```

2. add in **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "*": ["typings/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

This config is telling TS to look into `typings/` folder first when resolving any modules. If there's a match, use it, else, fallback to look up `node_modules/`.

With this setup, plus a soft link, we can kinda redirect the type definition of `react` to point to one of `preact`.

```
ln -s $PWD/node_modules/preact/src/index.d.ts $PWD/typings/react/index.d.ts
```

Comment: Kudos to your answer! This may sound stupid, but if TS is gonna look into `typings/` first, could I put both react and preact typings in it? BTW great pitch on preact!(although maybe you don't mean to promote it) I think I am gonna use it in my next project.

Comment: Yeah you can. You can also create your own customized `index.d.ts` file to selectively expose/modified the type definition of original lib. Do `import { Component } from "react"; interface MyComp extends Component { ... }; export { MyComp as Component };` whatever.

Comment: About the preact lib I don't mean to promote it. I personally feel that the only upside of preact is bundle size drop. Downside would be integrating with react-centric ecosystem can be troublesome. You run into nuances here and there, lead to unexpected problems quite hard to catch. :-/

Comment: If I am to promote anything, try out [svelte](https://svelte.dev) for your next project instead ;-)

Comment: LOL I'll try this trick and get back to you. Svelte does look promising. Will try that for sure! Also, thanks for that insider view about preact.

Comment: To be frank, the comic sans demo was the biggest hurdle that prevented me from trying svelte. I immediately lost interest in svelte the first time I saw that demo. But kind words about svelte keep coming back.

Comment: I am getting a module "path/to/@module/components/types" has no exported member 'AlternativePicker' message. Even though I specified paths related. What would be a good way to debug this?

Comment: By the way, instead of having another copy of `react` types inside typings, I added the original typing path of `react` to the paths, which is something like`'node_modules/react/types'`. Would this be a problem?

Comment: Actually I see issues in the `Respond-Native` indicating that the paths option is not yet supported. Feel defeated. But still a great answer! Thanks. I learnt a lot.